# How to solve a form of tridiagonal system of equations (with fringes?)

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I have read about the [Thomas algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tridiagonal_matrix_algorithm). Right now, I am trying to use it to solve the following linear system

$$\begin{bmatrix} b_1 & c_1 & 0 & \dots & 0 & a_1\\ a_2 & b_ 2 & c_2 & 0 & \dots & 0\\ 0 & a_3 & b_3 & c_3 & 0 & \dots\\ \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\ c_n & 0 & \dots & 0 & a_n & b_n\end{bmatrix} 
\begin{bmatrix}x_1\\x_2\\x_3\\ \vdots\\x_n\end{bmatrix} = 
\begin{bmatrix}r_1\\r_2\\r_3\\ \vdots\\r_n\end{bmatrix}$$
I have not been able to work out an algorithm for this matrix. Can someone point me to some reference that I can read about this? Thank you.

Comment: Does your matrix have any special properties? Is (strictly) diagonally dominant by rows or symmetric positive definite?

Comment: No. It's pretty much just a tridiagonal system of equations matrix except that the first and last row have an extra element like above.

Comment: Can you guarantee that the $a_i$, $b_i$, $c_i$ are not zero?

Comment: Yes. All three are non-zeroes.

Comment: My opinion (maybe I am wrong) is that you have too few zeros (25%) to expect a "miracle" solution compared to standard methods for solving a linear system.

Comment: I have edited it.

Answer (score 1):

The Thomas algorithm can be modified to solve this "periodic" case, as explained [here](http://www.cfm.brown.edu/people/gk/chap6/node14.html).

Comment: The link does not work anymore. Could you provide a different one?